# Function to DELETE rows taking the tablename as parameter

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-injection, plpgsql, sql-function

I want create a function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION medibv.delAuto(tableName nvarchar(50), columnName nvarchar(100),value 
 nvarchar(100))
 RETURNS void AS

$BODY$ 
begin 
DELETE from tableName  where columnName=value 

end; 
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I have these parameters: `tableName, columnName, value`.
I want `tableName` as table in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You don't seem to have got the "please include your PostgreSQL version and format your questions" message. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, http://stackoverflow.com/faq, and the info tab of [tag:postgresql]

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION medibv.delauto(tbl regclass, col text, val text
                                         ,OUT success bool)
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$ 
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('
   DELETE FROM %s
   WHERE  %I = $1
   RETURNING TRUE', tbl, col)
USING   val
INTO    success;

RETURN;  -- optional in this case

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT medibv.delauto('myschema.mytbl', 'my_txt_col', 'foo');
```

Returns `TRUE` or `NULL`.

- There is no `nvarchar` type in Postgres. You may be thinking of SQL Server. The equivalent would be `varchar`, but most of the time you can simply use `text`.
- `regclass` is a specialized type for registered table names. It's perfect for the case an prevents **SQL injection** for the table name automatically and most effectively. More in the related answer below.
- The column name is still prone to SQL injection. I sanitize the function with `format(%I)`.
- [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) requires PostgreSQL 9.1+.
- Your function did not report what happened. One or more rows may be found and deleted. Or none at all. As a *bare minimum* I added a `boolean OUT` column which will be `TRUE` if one or more rows were deleted. Because ([quoting the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)):

  > If multiple rows are returned, only the first will be assigned to the `INTO` variable.
- Lastly, use **`USING`** with `EXECUTE` to pass in **values**. Don't cast back and forth. This is inefficient and prone to errors and to SQLi once more.
- Find more explanation and links in this closely related answer:
  [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Answer (score 1):

Use [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to run dynamic commands:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION medibv.delAuto(tableName nvarchar(50), columnName nvarchar(100),value 
 nvarchar(100))
 RETURNS void AS

$BODY$ 
begin 
EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || tableName || ' WHERE ' || columnName || '=' || value; 

end; 
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: @LeNgocLoan: This is not valid Postgres syntax (nvarvchar? and you would need to at least quote the value to make it work at all) and one needs to at least address SQL injection here.

Comment: Only in case of Dynamic table names , EXECUTE should be used .Else you can just replace the variable name passed in a Function with the variable passed in SQL Command .

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xyz(abc integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
   declare
    --Declare your variables here
      begin
    ---DML Operation like Select or Delete
    DELETE FROM TableNAME Where Condition  LIMIT abc);
    GET DIAGNOSTICS v_cnt = ROW_COUNT;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
     RAISE NOTICE 'Error Occurred ';
    end;
  $BODY$